# NetSuite User Note saved search gives duplicate results

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I'm searching over user notes with no criteria. When I only included a few basic results columns (Date, Author, Title, Memo, Internal Id), there were 86 results.

Then I added another results column, a Formula (Numeric) field with the following formula: '[Sales Order #'||{transaction.transactionnumber}||'](/app/accounting/transactions/salesord.nl?id=%27||%7Btransaction.internalid%7D||%27)'

Now when I run the search, there are 6 results, and they are all identical.

[Search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb0cN.png)

Why are the duplicates showing up? I am aware that user notes show up on different records (Sales Order, Customer Record, etc). Could this be why?

I would like to be able to filter out those duplicates. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting duplicates because you are joining to a Transaction, and in NetSuite Searches, Transactions display one result per sublist line.

You'll want to add a `transaction.mainline` filter as well to only show body-level results for the Transaction.

Here's a video explaining the details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msNttISYovo